# MVC form with parametars:

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I use fileuploader Jquery, I tried to form defined as follows:

```
<Form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<%:Url.Action("Edit","Ticket")%>" method="post" >
```

using

```
(Html.BeginForm("Edit","Ticket",  new { ticketOnEdit = Model }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){}
```

Each of these ways is defined html form:

```
<form class="MultiFile-intercepted" method="post" action="21359" id="form1">
```

I do not have a parameter:

`enctype="multipart/form-data"`

How to solve a given problem, if someone can let me show what went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will generate the correct form:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Ticket", new { ticketOnEdit = Model }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) { %>
    ...
<% } %>
```

Like this (assuming of course default routes):

```
<form action="/Ticket/Edit" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: @Ivan, you still don't see the enctype attribute? That's weird. The helper works perfectly fine for me. There must something else going on with your code.

Comment: super, a solution to something ... I am confused